# System call open() permissions

Tags: c

I open a file using the system call `open()`.

```
if ((fd2 = open(logFile, O_RDWR |O_APPEND | O_CREAT ), 0666) == -1)
    DieWithError("open() failed");
```

My file which is FTP_track.log is created without any problem. The problem is although i have mode `0666`, which is read and write for all, I can not open the file in unix. I have to change permissions from the file's properties to read and write.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Probably your umask forbids write permission for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your line is that the parenthesis don't match up.  Your expression is parsed as `fd2 = open(), 0666`.  In C the expression `expr1, expr2` has the value `expr2` so your `if` statement basically says `fd2 = 0666`.

Comment: Agreed that the parentheses are wrong; disagree with analysis; assignment is higher precedence than comma, so it's `fd2 = open(...)` and then 0666 is the value compared with -1.

Comment: Thanks!!! You were right... its so strange that the file was creating properly, i had no errors , thanks again.