# File Descriptors, open() returns zero

Tags: c

i open a file and want to write something in it. The problem is that the fd2 for some reason is 0. Instead of writting in the file, it writes on terminal. I dont  close(0) anywhere in my code. Why do i get fd = 0 and not for example 3. The reason that writes on terminal is that the value of fd is zero? I know that fd = 0 is for standard input,

Any Ideas? Thank you.

```
if ((fd2 = open(logFile, O_RDWR |O_APPEND | O_CREAT , 0666) == -1))
    DieWithError("open() failed");

printf("FD2 = %d",fd2);     //returns me zero

bzero(tempStr, sizeof(tempStr));
bzero(hostname, sizeof(hostname));

gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));

sprintf(tempStr, "\n%sStarting FTP Server on host %s in port %d\n", ctime(&currentime), hostname, port);

if (write(fd2, tempStr, strlen(tempStr)) == -1)
    DieWithError("write(): failed");
```

Comment: What is `logfile`? Is it `/dev/console`?

Comment: If you're on Linux, run it through `strace`.

Comment: logFile is just a path to a logFile.log

Comment: If you can't reliably get your parentheses correct (and you can't — your other question, [System call open() permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168964/system-call-open-permissions), was also riddled with misplaced parentheses), then split things up: `fd2 = open(logFile, O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0666); if (fd2 == -1) { ... }`. You're much less likely to get this wrong.

Comment: As for why the log output appears on your terminal, the way things are normally set up is that standard input, standard output and standard error are often all read/write connections to your terminal, so you can write to standard input and read from standard output and standard error (and I had a dickens of a job typing that as I intended).  Hence, your mis-parenthesized expression ended with you writing to standard input, which is often writable when it is the terminal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your conditional is off. Mind the parentheses. It should be:

```
if ((fd2 = open(logFile, O_RDWR |O_APPEND | O_CREAT , 0666)) == -1)
//                                                        ^^^    ^^^
```

Sometimes it might be best not to outsmart yourself:

```
int fd = open(...);

if (fd == -1) { DieWithError(); }
```

Answer (score 7):

This is wrong.

```
if ((fd2 = open(logFile, O_RDWR |O_APPEND | O_CREAT , 0666) == -1))
```

You want this.

```
if ((fd2 = open(logFile, O_RDWR |O_APPEND | O_CREAT , 0666)) == -1)
```

It's hard to see because the line is so long, but the parentheses are in the wrong place.  In short,

```
if ((   fd2 = open(...) == -1     )) // your code
if ((   fd2 = (open(...) == -1)   )) // equivalent code
if ((   (fd2 = open(...)) == -1)  )) // correct code
```

If the line is so long, best to keep it out of the `if`...

```
#include <err.h>

fd2 = open(...);
if (fd2 < 0)
    err(1, "open failed");
```