# Why does the following code of read() call stall?

Tags: c, gcc

Got no warning compiling with gcc -Wall -W -g3 <*inputfile.c*> 
but binary doesn't show anything and not getting $ prompt.
gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13). I've taken it from the book Unix System Programming by Keith Haviland. Example of read() call.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<fcntl.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #define BUFSIZE 512
    int main()
    {
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    int fd;
    ssize_t nread;
    long total = 0;

    if( (fd = open("fi.txt", O_RDONLY) == -1)){
        printf("error in opening file\n");
        exit(1);
        }
    while( (nread = read(fd, buffer, BUFSIZE))>0)
    total += nread;
    printf("Total characters: %ld\n", total);
    exit(0);
}
```

I can't understand what gdb shows. fi.txt contains only one word, Hello.

```
:
.
(gdb) s
13      if( (fd = open("fi.txt", O_RDONLY) == -1)){
(gdb) s
open () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) print fd
No symbol "fd" in current context.
(gdb) s
0xb7fdbbd0 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function __kernel_vsyscall,
which has no line number information.
main () at usp5.c:17
17      while( (nread = read(fd, buffer, BUFSIZE))>0)
(gdb) print fd
$1 = 0
(gdb) s
read () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
0xb7fdbbd0 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function __kernel_vsyscall,
which has no line number information.
s
main () at usp5.c:19
19      printf("Total characters: %ld\n", total);
(gdb) print total
$2 = 0
(gdb) print nread
$3 = 2
(gdb) s
__printf (format=0x804863d "Total characters: %ld\n") at printf.c:28
28  printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) print total
No symbol "total" in current context.
(gdb) s
__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcat.S:55
55  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcat.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
__printf (format=0x804863d "Total characters: %ld\n") at printf.c:32
32  printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
33  in printf.c
(gdb) list
28  in printf.c
(gdb) s
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0xb7fb4e80 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=0x804863d "Total characters: %ld\n", 
    ap=0xbfffed84 "") at vfprintf.c:222
222 vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) list
......
```

It goes on and on printing similar messages.

Comment: You're missing a proper expression param set in your `open` conditional. [An **exact** duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169693/file-descriptors-open-returns-zero).

Answer (score 3):

You have misplaced brackets here:

```
if( (fd = open("fi.txt", O_RDONLY) == -1)){
```

which results in fd being set to 0, rather than the return value of open. Thus you are actually reading from fd 0 (STDIN).

It should be:

```
if( (fd = open("fi.txt", O_RDONLY)) == -1){
```

Comment: Thank you very much hermic. It's ok now. One question; the file fi.txt contains a 5 letter word Hello but it counts 6. Does it count the last \n?               Even wc -c shows 6.

Comment: Yes, all characters in the file will be counted, even \n.

Comment: I've used wc many many times but I wasn't aware of this feature. I thought wc -c counts only printable chars. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just make a low level mistake:

change this line code:

```
if( (fd = open("fi.txt", O_RDONLY) == -1)){
```

to

```
if( (fd = open("fi.txt", O_RDONLY)) == -1){
```

then you will get correct result.

because your code will make fd = 0, and 0 is the stdin, so the progrm always wait your input.

Comment: Thank you very much Spark Bao. I wrestled with it for all night long. I committed a very silly mistake. So sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[too long for a comment:]

Referring best practise debugging: If seemingly simple code fails, look for hidden unnecessarily complex but essential constructs and take them apart. In the case you show there are two such constructs:

1. Opening the file:

   ```
     if ((fd = open("fi.txt", O_RDONLY) == -1)) 
     {
       perror("open() failed");
       ...
   ```

   This could be written:

   ```
     fd = open("fi.txt", O_RDONLY);
     if (fd == -1) 
     {
       perror("open() failed");
       ...
   ```
2. Reading from the file:

   ```
     while ((nread = read(fd, buffer, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
   ```

   The could be written:

   ```
     nread = read(fd, buffer, BUFSIZE);
     while(nread > 0)      
     {
       ...
       nread = read(fd, buffer, BUFSIZE);
     }
     if (nread == -1) /* Add as much error checking as possible. */
     {
       perror("read() failed)");
     }
   ```

   Or more using only *one* call to `read()`, but *separating* error handling, for the cost of an additional `if` this way:

   ```
   do 
   {
     nread = read(fd, buffer, BUFSIZE);
     if (nread == -1) /* Add as much error checking as possible. */
     {
       perror("read() failed)");
     }
     else
     {
       ...
     }
   } while (nread > 0);
   ```

Comment: Thank you alk.
I've tried with all the constructs you stated here.                     
I should have used perror() but I doubt if it could be of any help as I placed brackets in a wrong position. 
perror() in this construct is not working; 
`if ((fd = open("fi.txt", O_RDONLY) == -1)) 
  {
    perror("open() failed");
    ... 
`                                                                                                                                                                 `
 but second part of your #1 is all right.

Comment: First part of your #2 I added one line as
 `nread = read(fd, buffer, BUFSIZE); 
 **total = nread;**                                                 
  while(nread > 0)      
  { 
...
`
then it works. Could you please tell me how I could get **nread** failed so I can test your #2 examples?

Comment: The easiest case is to pass an invalid file descriptor. Try `12345` or `INT_MAX` or alike. Any really big `int` should do. If it's larger then the maximum number of allowed file descriptors for the system you can very well be sure it's not a valid one .. ;-) Or just pass `-1` :-)